Sum of squares of xy bigger than sum of squares for x - how can that be?
I followed this tutorial to visualize R squared. First they define the formula to calculate sums of squares:

Then they apply the formula to get sums of squares of x1 and y:

Then they visualize the variances with an Euler diagram:

In their example ss_y is 400, ss_x1 is 292 and ss_both_y_x1 is 82. To find out what proportion of the x1variable is no part of y they do ss_x1 - ss_both_y_x1, which is 292 - 82 = 210.
I made up some data in R and if I do ss_x1 - ss_both_y_x1 with it I get negative values! How can it be that the variation x shared with y is bigger than the whole variation of x itself? So if we take the numbers from the screenshot above, then 292 < 82 (ss_x1 is smaller than ss_both_y_x1). To explain the problem visually with the Euler's diagram: The size of the dark gray area (area of 210 above) is negative for my data.
Here is what I do in R:
library(magrittr)
set.seed(1)
df <- data.frame(x1= rnorm(n= 1000, mean= 28, sd= 4))
df$y <- 2*df$x1 + 10*rnorm(n= nrow(df), mean= 0, sd= 1)

ss_both_y_x1 <- lm(formula= y ~ x1, data= df)%>% aov() %>% summary() %>% .[[1]] %>% .["x1", "Sum Sq"] # basically same code as in linked side but with no additional packages apart from magrittr
ss_x1 <- sum((df$x1 - mean(df$x1))^2)
ss_x1 < ss_both_y_x1
# TRUE


I think you have it the wrong way around; linear regression assumes x was observed without error. $\text{R}^2$ is rather the ratio of ss_xy over ss_y (which you didn't calculate).

@PBulls Yes, what you say is correct but in order to display the variances in an Euler diagram we need the SS mentioned in the question. I added the picture from the site linked in my question

In mathematics notation, what you are asking is that in a simple linear regression based on observed data $\{(x_i, y_i): i = 1, \ldots, n\}$, why the inequality
\begin{align*}
\sum_{i = 1}^n(x_i - \bar{x})^2 < \sum_{i = 1}^n(\hat{y}_i - \bar{y})^2 \tag{1}\label{1}
\end{align*}
can hold?
I don't see any reason why one can claim $\sum_{i = 1}^n(x_i - \bar{x})^2 \geq \sum_{i = 1}^n(\hat{y}_i - \bar{y})^2 $ must hold. $\eqref{1}$ can certainly hold if the range of $x$ is very tight while the range of $y$ is very dispersed. For example, consider the toy example that $n = 2$, $x_1 = -1, x_2 = 1, y_1 = 101, y_2 = -99$. It is easy to verify that
\begin{align*}
& \sum_{i = 1}^2(x_i - \bar{x})^2 = 1 + 1 = 2, \\
& \sum_{i = 1}^2(\hat{y}_i - \bar{y})^2 = 100^2 + 100^2 = 20000. 
\end{align*}
You probably confused the term $\sum_{i = 1}^n (x_i - \bar{x})^2$ with the sum of total squares $\sum_{i = 1}^n(y_i - \bar{y})^2$, under which case we do have $\sum_{i = 1}^n(y_i - \bar{y})^2 \geq \sum_{i = 1}^n(\hat{y}_i - \bar{y})^2 $, as a consequence of $SST = SSR + SSE$. I am afraid the terminology you used in the post (e.g., "the variation x shares with y") makes no sense to me -- the value saved in the variable ss_xy can hardly be interpreted as "variation of x shares with y" (ultimately, what does this verbatim mean?).

That is not the inequality my question is about. SS of x are smaller than SS of x shared with y, not SS of y itself. So why is xSS< xySS (and not why is xSS< ySS)

@LulY - what do you think "SS of x shared with y" means?  You appear to think it means "xySS", but "shared with" does not mean "multiplied by"...

@LulY I ran your code and confirmed that your ss_xy is just the "SSR" people normally referred to.

@jbowman Yes, there is no multiplication. See update of the question with screenshots of the relevant parts from the site linked

@LulY No matter how you updated the question, the quantity lm(formula= y ~ x, data= df)%>% aov() %>% summary() %>% .[[1]] %>% .["x", "Sum Sq"] in your code is equal to $SSR$ but not anything else, have yourself verified this?

Yes. They call it ss_both_y_x1 and I understand it as the y variance determined by x1. In the Euler's diagram it is 82. The y variance determined by x1 should not be bigger than variance of x1 itself. 82 should not be bigger than 292 (numbers from Euler's diagram)

lm(formula= y ~ x, data= df)%>% aov() %>% summary() %>% .[[1]] %>% .["x", "Sum Sq"] is bigger than ss(df$x) but how can this be? This is the question. Or in other words: the dark gray area can't be negative (the 210 area)

The variance determined by x1 can certainly be bigger than the variance of x1 itself.  Consider $y = a + 2x + e$; the variance of the contribution of $x$ to $y$ will be four times the variance of $x$ itself.

"the variation x shares with y" means they covariate, the proportion that y is determined by x

I added an answer

Sums of squares are scale dependent and in my example the y variable varies more than x1. That is why ss_x1 - ss_both_y_x1 gave negative values. But if we z standardize x1 and y before, all works out. In other words, after z standardizing both variables ss_x1 > ss_both_y_x1 holds. I have no proof for that. I simply run thousands times random data with the code and ss_x1 > ss_both_y_x1 always was the case. And it is what we should expect since we can not have a negative proportion.
Unfortunately, the linked tutorial simply says to use ss_x1 - ss_both_y_x1for the dark gray area (see Eulers diagram), but depending on data used, one should standardize before to find the proportions.
In R it is
library(magrittr)
# set.seed(1) # runs with any random data
df <- data.frame(x1= rnorm(n= 1000, mean= 28, sd= 4))
df$y <- 2*df$x1 + 10*rnorm(n= nrow(df), mean= 0, sd= 1)
df$x1 <- scale(df$x1, TRUE, TRUE)
df$y <- scale(df$y, TRUE, TRUE)

ss_both_y_x1 <- lm(formula= y ~ x1, data= df)%>% aov() %>% summary() %>% .[[1]] %>% .["x1", "Sum Sq"] # basically same code as in linked side but with no additional packages apart from magrittr
ss_x1 <- sum((df$x1 - mean(df$x1))^2)
ss_x1 < ss_both_y_x1
# FALSE!

